# Error in OleDbConnection.Open() when trying to read Excel XLSB

Tags: excel, model-view-controller, oledbconnection

I'm using Visual Studio 2013 with MVC 3 Razor. I'm able to upload and save XLSB file, and I'm trying to read data from the uploaded XLSB. I have the below connection string and method to initialize the OleDbConnection:

```
strConStr = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=C:\Projects\Excel1.xlsb;Extended Properties='Excel 8.0;HDR=True'";
OleDbConnection connExcel = new OleDbConnection(strConStr);
```

The error occur at connExcel.Open(). Below is the error message:

> An exception of type 'System.Data.OleDb.OleDbException' occurred in System.Data.dll but was not handled in user code
>
> Additional information: This file was created in a previous beta version of Excel 2007.  Open the file with Excel 2007 to save it to the most recent version of the Excel 2007 file format before opening the file in Access 2007.

I had AccessDatabaseEngine installed in my PC. In my control panel, I have the following installed engine info:

> Name: Microsoft Office Access database engine 2007 (English)
> ,Size: 19.2 MB
> ,Version: 12.0.4518.1031

I'm not sure if this is the correct version to read XLSB file. My PC is x64 bit by the way.

My colleague also have the same type of Microsoft Office Access database engine 2007 installed in his PC but his version is "12.0.66XX", the code works fine on his side.

Please let me know if I need to install another version of Access Database Engine, or any other way to resolve this error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm able to resolve this after a long studies and research.

Apart of the Microsoft Office Access database engine 2007 that is already installed in my machine, I also download and install [Microsoft Access Database Engine 2010 Redistributable](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=13255).

After that, I need to download [Microsoft Office Access Runtime and Data Connectivity 2007 Service Pack 2 (SP2)](http://www.microsoft.com/en-au/download/details.aspx?id=7020) to install and then reboot my machine.

Everything work like magic afterwards.

And this is my working connection string:

```
strConStr = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=C:\Projects\Excel1.xlsb;Extended Properties='Excel 12.0;HDR=True'";
```